# Piwik Visitor Location(Country) and Visitor Map not showing properly

Tags: analytics, matomo

Piwik Visitor Location (Country) and Visitor Map by default it is showing United States.

I attached one website to piwik and i accessed from India no one accessed from United States but it is showing United States Visitors. Why?

Answer (score 0):

By default Piwik uses the browser language to guess the visitor country. You may use your browser in english for example. In any case, the default geolocation system is very basic.

If you want accurate geolocation, have a look at the options here: http://piwik.org/docs/geo-locate/

Comment: I already installed Geoip(php) database[Geolitecity,Geolite country] but it is showing UnitedStates visitors. i tried with Geoip(pecl) but when i add "extension=php_geoip.dll" in php.ini file apache server is not starting.